# matplotlib Legend Markers Only Once

Tags: python, matplotlib

I often plot a point on a matplotlib plot with:

```
x = 10
y = 100
plot(x, y, "k*", label="Global Optimum")
legend()
```

However, this causes the legend to put a star in the legend twice, such that it looks like:

```
* * Global Optimum
```

when I really want it to look like:

```
 *  Global Optimum
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I wish I could upvote this question multiple times. I HATE the default `numpoints=2` convention and was relieved to see someone had already taken the time to ask about it and get an answer.

Comment: Mind: the option for scatterplots is `scatterpoints=1`

Answer (score 255, accepted):

This should work:

```
legend(numpoints=1)
```

BTW, if you add the line

```
legend.numpoints     : 1      # the number of points in the legend line
```

to your matplotlibrc file, then this will be the new default.

[See also scatterpoints, depending on your plot.]

API: [Link to API docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend)

Comment: Thanks. I ran into this today also. Why is this not the default?

Comment: Could you add a link to the api? http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend  I could just edit it in myself, but that seems rude.

Comment: ignore my deleted comments about why the default is what it is, they are wrong.

Comment: Is there any way to reduce the area the point take on the legend?

Comment: @MarcosAlex: the last line of the answer says "See also scatterpoints, depending on your plot."

Comment: @DMS: I had not seen that. My mistake. You should also highlight it as code in order to make it more visible.

Comment: At long last, there are plans for numpoints=1 to be default in matplotlib 2.0!  Huzzah! https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4854

Comment: @Yotam I use handletextpad=0, which minimizes the distance between the point and its label (hence, reducing the area). I use it as in here: legend(frameon=False,fontsize=12,numpoints=1,handletextpad=0) I found it by printing mpl.rcParams and searching the "legend" options inside.

Answer (score 24):

I like to change my matplotlib rc parameters dynamically in every python script. To achieve this goal I simply use somthing like that at the beginning of my python files.

```
from pylab import *
rcParams['legend.numpoints'] = 1
```

This will apply to all plots generated from my python file.

EDIT: For those who do not like to import pylab, the long answer is

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['legend.numpoints'] = 1
```