# Elegant way to match a string to a random color matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to translate the labels of some data to colors for graphing with matplotlib

I have a list of names `["bob", "joe", "andrew", "pete"]`

Is there a built in way to map these strings with color values in matplotlib? I thought about randomly creating hex values but I could end up with similar colors or non visible colors.

I've tried a couple different ways of trying to create key values from the below cmap answer:

this:

```
#names is a list of distinct names
cmap = plt.get_cmap('cool')
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, len(names)))
clr = {names[i]: colors[i] for i in range(len(names))}
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=clr)
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139423/plot-different-color-for-different-categorical-levels-using-matplotlib

Comment: and https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6214

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Choose a [color map](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html), such as `viridis`:

```
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
```

The colormap, `cmap`, is a function which can take an array of values from 0 to 1 and map them to RGBA colors. `np.linspace(0, 1, len(names))` produces an array of equally spaced numbers from 0 to 1 of length `len(names)`.  Thus,

```
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, len(names)))
```

selects equally-spaced colors from the `viridis` color map.

Note that this is not using the *value* of the string, it only uses the *ordinal position* of the string in the list to select a color. Note also that these are not *random* colors, this is just an easy way to generate unique colors from an arbitrary list of strings.

---

So:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
names = ["bob", "joe", "andrew", "pete"]
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, len(names)))
print(colors)
# [[ 0.267004  0.004874  0.329415  1.      ]
#  [ 0.190631  0.407061  0.556089  1.      ]
#  [ 0.20803   0.718701  0.472873  1.      ]
#  [ 0.993248  0.906157  0.143936  1.      ]]

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi*2, 100)
for i, (name, color) in enumerate(zip(names, colors), 1):
    plt.plot(x, np.sin(x)/i, label=name, c=color)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

The problem with

```
clr = {names[i]: colors[i] for i in range(len(names))}
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=clr)
```

is that the `c` parameter of `ax.scatter` expects a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-sequence) of RGB(A)
values of the same length as `x` or a single color. `clr` is a dict, not a sequence. So 
if `colors` is the same length as `x` then you could use

```
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=colors)
```

Comment: I am trying to input these as the c argument in 3d scatter I tried zip(names, colors) #names is the list of names and colors is the cmap# and I got an error in matplotlib. Is there a way around this

Comment: Could you post the code and the full traceback error message?

Comment: I added what I tried to do by turning it into a dictionary

Comment: The `c` parameter of `ax.scatter` expects a sequence (such as a list or array) of RGB(A) values, it does not accept a dict. So if you want a different color for each value of `x,y,z`, then use `c=colors` instead of `c=clr`.

Answer (score 10):

I use the hash function to get numbers between 0 and 1, you can use this even when you don't know all the labels:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
labels = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "a"]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

colors = [float(hash(s) % 256) / 256 for s in labels]      

plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors, cmap="jet")
plt.show()
```

Comment: This answer was a great inspiration for me to solve the problem. But one thing that could be wrong with it, is that `hash(s) % 256` could be the same for two different strings in `labels`.

Answer (score 1):

This has upset me so much, that I have written `get_cmap_string` that returns a function which works exactly as `cmap` but acts also on strings.

```py
data = ["bob", "joe", "pete", "andrew", "pete"]
cmap = get_cmap_string(palette='viridis', domain=data)
cmap("joe")
# (0.20803, 0.718701, 0.472873, 1.0)
cmap("joe", alpha=0.5)
# (0.20803, 0.718701, 0.472873, 0.5)
```

---

## 1. Implementation

The basic idea as mentioned by all other answers is that we need a hash table -- a mapping from our strings to integers, which is unique. In python this is just a dictionary.

The reason `hash(str)` won't work, is that even though matplotlib's `cmap` accepts any integer, it is possible for two different strings to get the same color. For example, if `hash(str1)` is `8` and `hash(str2)` is `18`, and we initialize `cmap` as `get_cmap(name=palette, lut=10)` then `cmap(hash(str1))` will be the same as `cmap(hash(str2))`

#### Code

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm
def get_cmap_string(palette, domain):
    domain_unique = np.unique(domain)
    hash_table = {key: i_str for i_str, key in enumerate(domain_unique)}
    mpl_cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap(palette, lut=len(domain_unique))

    def cmap_out(X, **kwargs):
        return mpl_cmap(hash_table[X], **kwargs)

    return cmap_out
```

---

## 2. Usage

Example as in other answers, but now note that the name `pete` appears twice.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
names = ["bob", "joe", "pete", "andrew", "pete"]

# color map for the data
cmap = get_cmap_string(palette='viridis', domain=names)

# example usage
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi*2, 100)
for i_name, name in enumerate(names):
    plt.plot(x, np.sin(x)/i_name, label=name, c=cmap(name))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: example usage]

You can see, that the entries in the legend are duplicated. Solving this is another challenge, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385639/duplicate-items-in-legend-in-matplotlib).
Or use a custom legend instead as explained [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html).

## 3. Alternatives

As far the discussion by matplotlib devs goes, they recommend using Seaborn.
See discussion [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6214) and an example usage [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/errorband_lineplots.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```py
names = ["bob", "joe", "andrew", "pete"]

colmap = {name: n for n, name in enumerate(set(names))} # <-- uses 'set' to get unique names from list

ax.scatter(
    x, y, z, 
    c = [colmap[name] for name in names],
    cmap = 'tab10' # <-- not necessary but helpful if you want to make sure colors aren't similar
)
```

It just turns the names into integers, and matplotlib automatically decides how to convert integers into colors. You can ensure colors won't be similar if you use a [qualitative colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html), like `tab10`