# Duplicate Legend Entries in Pyplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

The following function results in a pyplot with duplicate legend entries for 'Actual' (see image link below). This function is called within a larger body of code that may loop as many times as desired but, regardless of the number of iterations, the legend entry is only ever duplicated once. Furthermore, I have designed the function to be independent from iterations; the iteration variable is passed as an integer and is only used to access a corresponding csv file in the same directory.

I have tried adding pyplot.close() at the beginning and end of the function with no luck. I have also tried the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385639/duplicate-items-in-legend-in-matplotlib), which did successfully remove the duplicate legend entry but resulted in both legend entries having the same color.

```
def show_total_num_tests(run_number):
    model_series = pandas.read_csv('timeSeries%s.csv' % run_number, index_col="Day", usecols=['Day', 'Tests Today'])
    actual_series = pandas.read_csv('data_total_tests.csv')
    pyplot.plot(model_series, label='Predicted')
    pyplot.plot(actual_series, label='Actual')
    pyplot.legend()
    pyplot.xlabel("Day")
    pyplot.ylabel("Number of Tests Administered")
    pyplot.title("Total Number of COVID19 Tests Administered)")
    pyplot.show()
```

[image: Image of Code Output - Reputation doesn't allow embedding]

Comment: What does `actual_series` look like?

Comment: I Did a MWE for a question I had and had the same problem. It turned out I was calling the function twice in separate places.

Comment: Do you need iterating colors? Because if you don't you can use the solution you found and set the colors manually with the `color` kwarg