# Avoid duplicate labels in matplotlib with x, y of form [[...], [...] ...]

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, visualization

Firstly, let me post a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385639/duplicate-items-in-legend-in-matplotlib) to a similar post but with a slight difference.

I am having trouble to create legend with unique labels with input data of form:

```
    idl_t, idl_q = [[0, 12, 20], [8, 14, 24]], [[90, 60, 90], [90, 60, 90]]
```

and plotting is as following:

```
    plt.plot(idl_t, idl_q, label="Some label")
```

The results is that I have multiple labels of the same text. The link posted before was having similar problems the OP there was using data of format:

```
idl_t, idl_q = [1,2], [2,3]
```

which is different from my case and I am not sure if the logic there can be applied to my case

So the question is how do I avoid duplicate labels without changing data input?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the handles and labels used to make the legend and modify them. In the code below, these labels/handles are made into a dictionary which keeps unique dictionary keys (associated with your labels here), leading to loosing duplicate labels. (You may want to manipulate them differently to achieve your goal.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

idl_t, idl_q = [[0, 12, 20], [8, 14, 24]], [[90, 60, 90], [90, 60, 90]]
plt.plot(idl_t, idl_q, label="Some label")

# get legend handles and their corresponding labels
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()

# zip labels as keys and handles as values into a dictionary, ...
# so only unique labels would be stored 
dict_of_labels = dict(zip(labels, handles))

# use unique labels (dict_of_labels.keys()) to generate your legend
plt.legend(dict_of_labels.values(), dict_of_labels.keys())

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot showing unique labels in the legend.]

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in a single line, but I am afraid it does not seem to read that well.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(zip(*idl_t), zip(*idl_q))):
    ax.plot(x, y, label="Label" if i == 0 else "_nolabel_")
```

Maybe something like this is simpler to understand:

```py
for i in range(len(idl_t)):
    ax.plot(
        [xval[i] for xval in idl_t], 
        [yval[i] for yval in idl_q],
        label="Label" if i == 0 else "_nolabel_"
    ) 

ax.legend()
```

In case you want to plot `[0, 12, 20]` with `[90, 60, 90]`, and `[8, 14, 24]` with `[90, 60, 90]`:

```py
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(idl_t, idl_q)):
    ax.plot(x, y, label="Label" if i == 0 else "_nolabel_")

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I am plotting lines x: idl_t[0][i] to idl_t[1][i] with y =  idl_q[0][i] to idl_q[1][i].