# Python: Deleting extra characters in map legend, and making characters fit in legend

Tags: python, dictionary, legend

Python noob here, so I apologize if this is an easy fix. I just need one circle next to the text in this legend. However, my code is outputting two circles for each plot. And it's not necessarily fitting in the legend box.

```
p1, = plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', ms=10)
p2, = plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', ms=20)
p3, = plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', ms=25)
plt.legend([p1,p2,p3], ["< 50 Homes","< 100 Homes",
                                ">100 Homes"], loc = 3)
```

It's almost working out, but just not there. Thanks in advance for the advice!

Comment: +1 though I don't think this could be achieved.

Comment: Not sure I follow. +1? Think it would it be better to try this a different way?

Comment: +1 means I'm upvoting your question (and also wanna know if there is a way to get what your need, though I don't have an answer myself) ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146778/matplotlib-legend-markers-only-once

Comment: Thanks for the +1 Zhangxoachen! Adding numpoints=1 per Wojciech's link worked. BIG help. Thanks!!