# Setting numpoints in matplotlib legend does not work

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am trying to have a single data point on a plot legend by following the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146778/matplotlib-legend-markers-only-once) and it does not seem to work:

```
from pylab import scatter
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.scatter(1,2,c = 'blue', marker = 'x')
ax.scatter(2,3, c= 'red', marker = 'o')
ax.legend(('1','2'), loc = 2, numpoints = 1)
plt.show()
```

[image: code output]

Am I doing something completely stupid here? Some additional information:

```
In [147]:  import matplotlib 
           print matplotlib.__version__

Out [147]: 1.1.1rc
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For scatterplots, use the [scatterpoints](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) parameter:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(1, 2, c='blue', marker='x')
ax.scatter(2, 3, c='red', marker='o')
ax.legend(('1', '2'), loc=2, scatterpoints=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, would've never guessed this. Using two different parameters to do pretty much the same thing seems quite pointless.

Comment: Axes can contain both line plots and scatter plots, so having two parameters, `scatterpoints` and `numpoints`, allows you to control the look of those legend items independently.