# Scatter plots in Pandas/Pyplot: How to plot by category with different markers

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Building on this earlier question: [Scatter plots in Pandas/Pyplot: How to plot by category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654635/scatter-plots-in-pandas-pyplot-how-to-plot-by-category).

The code below is the solution to that post and plots each group as a different color.  How would one also plot each group as different marker?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1974)

# Generate Data
num = 20
x, y = np.random.random((2, num))
labels = np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'], num)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, y=y, label=labels))

groups = df.groupby('label')

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.margins(0.05) # Optional, just adds 5% padding to the autoscaling
for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.x, group.y, marker='o', linestyle='', ms=12, label=name)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you iterate over your groups, you can iterate over a list of markers using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). The code below will iterate over the `markers` list and assign each element, in turn, using `marker=marker` in the `ax.plot` line.

I've also added [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) which will cause the iteration to go to the beginning once the end is reached, this means that if you have more than 3 groups then it won't fail. If you had 4 groups then the markers would be `'x', 'o', '^', 'x'`, for example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1974)

from itertools import cycle

# Generate Data
num = 20
x, y = np.random.random((2, num))
labels = np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'], num)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, y=y, label=labels))

groups = df.groupby('label')

markers = ['x', 'o', '^']

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.margins(0.05) # Optional, just adds 5% padding to the autoscaling
for (name, group), marker in zip(groups, cycle(markers)):
    ax.plot(group.x, group.y, marker=marker, linestyle='', ms=12, label=name)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot]

Comment: How do you remove the redundant column in the legend?

Comment: @invictus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146778/matplotlib-legend-markers-only-once/6146871#6146871 will probably help.