# Matplotlib: 3D Scatter plots not recognizing labels

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I believe a similar question to this was asked before, but it didn't really clarify things for me.

Basically, I have a list of tuples, each of which functions as a point (so (x, y, z) for example).

I want to plot them in either 2D or 3D after I run a clustering algorithm (that color codes the points).

```
clusters = []
def plotPoints(self):
    fig = plt.figure()
    if self.clusters[0].dimensions == 2:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        for i in range(0, len(self.clusters)):
            ax.scatter(*zip(*self.clusters[i].points), c=self.clusters[i].color, marker="o", label=("Cluster " + str(i + 1)))
        plt.legend(loc='upper left')
        plt.show()
    elif self.clusters[0].dimensions == 3:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
        for i in range(0, len(self.clusters)):
            ax.scatter(*zip(*self.clusters[i].points), c=self.clusters[i].color, marker="o", label=("Cluster " + str(i + 1)))
        plt.legend(loc='upper left')
        plt.show()
    else:
        print "Cannot plot in dimensions lower than 2 or higher than 3"
```

Cluster class:

```
class Cluster(object):
centroid = ()
dimensions = 0
color = 'k'

def __init__(self, init_pt, color):
    self.points = []
    self.points.append(init_pt)
    self.dimensions = len(init_pt)
    self.centroid = init_pt
    self.color = color

def addPoint(self, pt):
    try:
        if len(pt) != self.dimensions:
            raise ArithmeticError("Wrong number of dimensions on new point, ignoring")
        else:
            centroid_dim_list = []
            for dim in range(0, self.dimensions):
                centroid_dim_list.append((self.centroid[dim] * len(self.points) + pt[dim]) / float(len(self.points) + 1))
            self.centroid = tuple(centroid_dim_list)
            self.points.append(pt)
    except ArithmeticError as ae:
        print ae.message
        pass
```

2D plots work just fine (and look really nice), but 3D plots give me a warning:

```
UserWarning: No labeled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots.
  warnings.warn("No labeled objects found. "
```

And no legend appears. But I am labeling the points, and the code I am using is almost identical, so I am confused as to what the problem is. I heard something about a proxy object, but I have no clue how to use that for this case.

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: Using version 1.3.1, I think. That's the version that is available from the repo with my version of linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I partially solved my problem by adding the following code:

```
ax.plot([], [], 'o', c=self.clusters[i].color, label="Cluster " + str(i + 1))
```

to each iteration of the loop, giving the following figure.

[image]

The marker is doubled for some reason, but at least it mostly works. If someone can comment on why it is doubled that would be great.

**Edit**
Per jedwards comment, I fixed it by changing my legend() call to:

```
plt.legend(numpoints=1 , loc='upper left')
```

Comment: re: double markers, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146778/matplotlib-legend-markers-only-once)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the format of your `self.clusters` is, but with something I came up with that I think closely resembles it, I was able to produce the following:

[image: 1]

With the code

```
for i,c in enumerate(self.clusters):
    x,y,z = c.points
    ax.text(x,y,z, "Cluster %d" % (i+1), None)
```

Based off [text3d demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/text3d_demo.html).

I'm using matplotlib 1.4.3

**Note**, you won't be able to "drag and drop" this code, since my cluster instances are simple 3-tuples, yours seem more complicated.

Comment: My clusters are lists of 3-tuples, and I have a list of them (the clusters), so it probably would work. I don't want the text labels to show. I'll include more code in the question.

Comment: Tried that, shows the label on the graph, but I just want the legend to work, and it still shows the same warning.

Answer (score 1):

I may not fully understood your question, but here is an example you may tweak it to your case. Hope it helps:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from random import randint

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# dataset
def data():
    return [randint(0,100) for _ in range(10)]

c1 = (data(), data(), data())
c2 = (data(), data(), data())
c3 = (data(), data(), data())
clusters = [c1, c2, c3]

# plot 
colors = ['r', 'b', 'y', 'c']
for i, c in enumerate(clusters):
    ax.scatter(c[0], c[1], c[2], c=colors[i], label='cluster {}'.format(i))

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1.5, 1))
plt.show()
```

It produces this:
[image]